# how to access all variables from a different file in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, fetch

I have a javascript file in which I fetch some data using an api, after getting the data, I want to redirect the user to a new page.

I'm able to redirect the user but in that case, I'm not able to access the variables from the previous page.

```
function getData(key) {
fetch(key)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then((json)=> {
        data = json;
        window.location.href = 'Live Weather.html'
    })
```

}

After doing this the functions defined for the previous page shows an error of null and the data variable is also not accessable even though the data has stored value before the redirection of the page.

Comment: You can’t do that. Why not do the Ajax on the new page

Answer (score 1):

Assigning to `window.location.href` is a little counterintuitive as it behaves more like a function that loads the next page, closing the current page (and javascript runtime) in the process. In a multi-page site it is not possible to 'reach around' page reloads directly in javascript, but there are several alternative solutions to this, the best one will depend on your use case:

1. Build your site as a [single page application](https://medium.com/@NeotericEU/single-page-application-vs-multiple-page-application-2591588efe58)
2. Use [session storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)
3. Use iframes with [postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)